# How to check what the first word in clipboard is?

Tags: autohotkey

Lets say my `Cliboard` variable is currently in this state:

```
Clipboard:= "-Classes Essay on Hobbes
```

I want to perform `If` conditions depending on the first block/word in the clipboard, in this case `-Classes` . Essentially doing something like below using `FileAppend`:

```
if "-diary"{
    ;Create file in /Diary/Entry 27.MD
}

Else if  "-Classes"{
    ;Create file in /Classes/Essay on Hobbes.MD
}
```

I was able to find this page in the docs [If Var in/contains MatchList - Syntax & Usage | AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfIn.htm) but its not positional, which means if the block `-Classes` is also present as part of the file name for some reason, my logic breaks.

I have taken the liberty to crosspost this question on other forums as well.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or.. you can just:

```
Clipboard:= "-Classes Essay on Hobbes"
Gosub % subroutine := SubStr( Clipboard, 1, InStr( Clipboard, " " )-1 )

Clipboard:= "-diary diary example"
Gosub % subroutine := SubStr( Clipboard, 1, InStr( Clipboard, " " )-1 )
Return

-diary:
    MsgBox % "Diary:`n"  StrReplace( clipboard, subroutine " " ) 
    ;Create file in /Diary/Entry 27.MD
Return

-Classes:
    MsgBox % "Classes:`n"  StrReplace( clipboard, subroutine " " )
    ;Create file in /Classes/Essay on Hobbes.MD
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try `StrSplit()`

```
; Array := StrSplit(String , Delimiters, OmitChars, MaxParts)
clip_array := StrSplit(Clipboard, A_Space, , 1)

if clip_array[1] = "-diary"{
    ;Create file in /Diary/Entry 27.MD
}

Else if clip_array[1] = "-Classes"{
    ;Create file in /Classes/Essay on Hobbes.MD
}

Else {
    MsgBox % "No match for " clip_array[1]
}
```

Described here https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StrSplit.htm and note the param for `MaxParts` which addresses how many "tokens" to look in to (keeping the rest in the last) if the clipboard is sufficiently large to matter (in which case I'm not sure any of the other answers address any better).

Comment: So I tested both on various string lengths. Regex still averages out to be faster, albeit I had to use the dllcall  “queryperformancecounter” to actually find the difference, since it is only a few micro seconds faster. This was over 14 tests from string lengths of 96-200,000+ chars.  Strsplit seemed to work better for lengths of a few thousand the best, and regex much faster for short strings. Avg strsplit .245ms, avg regex .192ms overall. To be honest I thought you might be right, since I am not super familiar with regex “under the hood”

Answer (score 1):

If the amount of text on the clipboard is enormous, that could cause lagging with the script loading all of that text into the script memory, just to check the first value. I'd recommend regexMatch since that can return a position and capture the word as well without parsing everything.

```
; for reference of regexMatch function
; regexMatch(Haystack, Needle, outputVar, startPos)

Fnd := regexMatch(Clipboard, "U)(\-[\w]+))", capSubStr, inStr(Clipboard, "-"))
if (Fnd==0) {
    Msgbox, Didn't find a word on the Clipboard.
    Return
}
checkVal := capSubStr1
if (checkVal=="-diary") {
    ;Create file in /Diary/Entry 27.MD
} Else if (checkVal=="-Classes") {
    ;Create file in /Classes/Essay on Hobbes.MD
}
```

Here is the basic reference for using regular expressions with AHK: https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm

That will give an idea as to what the above expression is actually looking for, if you are not already familiar with regex.

Comment: RegEx is by far more of a laborious process with a large clipboard that the OP wants the rest of to use in the further processing. My better answer with `StrSpl()` instead and the `MaxParts` param handle more efficiently, I'd guess, by far. Ymmv and curious what OP learns.

Comment: The only issue I see with your solution is that it assumes the first word will always end with a space, but what if it ends with a LF? The later string comparison would fail. I’d stick with regexMatch, this solution provides latitude.